# R - double boxplot in one chart based on 3 variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

The problem is to have two charts based on different columns in one chart

[How chart should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Kuc.png)

example data

```
set.seed(42) 
data <- data.frame(Id=1:20, 
Q_3_1=sample(1:6, 20, replace=TRUE), 
Q_3_2=sample(1:6, 20, replace=TRUE), 
Level=sample(c("AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD"), 20, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Do not post data as images. We cannot copy/paste that into R for testing. Show your attempts so far and make it clear where you are getting stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, here is a `tidyverse` solution:

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Data

```
set.seed(42) 
data <- data.frame(Id=1:20, 
                   Q_3_1=sample(1:6, 20, replace=TRUE), 
                   Q_3_2=sample(1:6, 20, replace=TRUE), 
                   Level=sample(c("AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD"), 20, replace=TRUE))
```

### Plot code

```
data %>% 
   #Pivot data to create a single column with all values from Q_3_1 to Q_3_2
   pivot_longer(cols = Q_3_1:Q_3_2) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(name,value, fill = Level))+
   geom_boxplot()
```

### Output

[image]